# Unexpected NOT EQUAL TO NULL comparison in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have below table in MySQL.

```
city_data
+------+-----------+-------------+
|  id  | city_code | city_name   |
+------+-----------+-------------+
| 4830 | BHR       | Bharatpur   |
| 4831 | KEP       | Nepalgunj   |
| 4833 | OHS       | Sohar       |
| 4834 | NULL      | Shirdi      |
+------+-----------+-------------+
```

and below query.

**select id,city_code,city_name from city_data where city_code != 'BHR';**

I was expecting 3 rows.

```
| 4831 | KEP       | Nepalgunj   |
| 4833 | OHS       | Sohar       |
| 4834 | NULL      | Shirdi      |
+------+-----------+-------------+
```

But getting only 2 rows.

```
| 4831 | KEP       | Nepalgunj   |
| 4833 | OHS       | Sohar       |
+------+-----------+-------------+
```

I am not able to understand why the row

```
| 4834 | NULL      | Shirdi      |
```

Not includes in the result of my query. The where condition(NULL != 'BHR') should have been passed.

Please, someone, help to clear the doubt.

Comment: `select id,city_code,city_name from city_data where COALESCE(city_code,'-1') != 'BHR';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MySQL Reference Manual, section 3.3.4.6: Working with NULL values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html) the following is why:

> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also
>   NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.
>
> In MySQL, 0 or NULL means false and anything else means true. The
>   default truth value from a boolean operation is 1.

This means that `NULL != 'BHR'` will evaluate to `NULL`, which in turn will mean `false` to MySQL. In order for the query to work as you want, you have to append `OR city_code IS NULL` to your query.

Comment: Yes. **The result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL.** explains all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare null values with `!=`, because it is null, use `IS NULL` predicate instead:

```
select id,city_code,city_name 
from city_data 
where city_code != 'BHR' OR city_code IS NULL;
```

Comment: You don't want to use COALESCE?  Faster!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>. Therefore query is confusing and NULL record is being ignored. for more info go to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp